# Dual of the space of all bounded functions, $B(X, \mathbb{R}).$

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let  $X$ be a non compact separable metric space. Denote 
by $B(X, \mathbb{R})$ the set  of all bounded real functions 
endowed with the sup norm, this is a Banach space. Denote by 
$C_b(X,\mathbb{R})\subset B(X, \mathbb{R})$  the subspace of 
all continuous functions, which with the induced norm is also 
a Banach space.

**Question 1.:**
What  are the dual spaces 
$(C_b(X,\mathbb{R}))^{*}$, $(B(X, \mathbb{R}))^{*}$? Also, is  there 
some way to give a sense to $(C_b(X,\mathbb{R}))^{*}\subset(B(X, \mathbb{R}))^{*}$?

**Question 2**:  If $K\subset X$ is a compact subset we know that 
$(C(K, \mathbb{R}))^{*}$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal{M}(K)$ the space of
the radon  measures on $K$. Is there some way to see an element
of $(C(K, \mathbb{R}))^{*}$ as a element of
 $(C_b(X,\mathbb{R}))^{*}$ or $(B(X, \mathbb{R}))^{*}$?

Comment: $C_b(X)^*\cong M(\beta X)$, $B(X)^*\cong M(\beta X_d)$, where $X_d$ is $X$ endowed with the discrete topology. As for your second question you have only a surjection from one of the latter spaces onto $C(K)^*$.

Comment: The canonical place to look is Dunford and Schwartz.

Comment: For Question 2: Every $f\in C(K,\mathbb{R})$ extends to a function in $C_b(X,\mathbb{R})$. So $\mathcal{M}(K)$ embeds into $(C_b(X,\mathbb{R})^\ast$ in a natural way.